# Can't create table in DB2

Tags: java, sql, eclipse, db2

I can't create the table in DB2 via Eclipse. I've been stuck for a long time and I've searched a lot for the following error:

> Error SQLCODE=-204

Below is my code:

```
CREATE TABLE BaseEntity( 
    wts Timestamp NOT NULL, 
    siteID NOT NULL, 
    oid varchar2(11), 
    PRIMARY KEY (oid),
    AccelerationVector varchar2(8),
    DeadReckoningAlgorithm varchar2(8),
    Orientation varchar2(8),
    WorldLocation varchar2(8),
    VelocityVector varchar2(8) 
)
```

> com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlSyntaxErrorException: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-204, SQLSTATE=42704, SQLERRMC=NOT, DRIVER=3.63.123

```
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.fd.a(fd.java:679)
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.fd.a(fd.java:60)
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.fd.a(fd.java:127)
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.ho.b(ho.java:2317)
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.ho.c(ho.java:2300)
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.cb.l(cb.java:370)
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.cb.a(cb.java:62)
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.q.a(q.java:50)
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.tb.b(tb.java:220)
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.io.lc(io.java:3318)
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.io.b(io.java:4275)
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.io.dc(io.java:759)
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.io.executeUpdate(io.java:742)
at testDB.XmlToDBSchema.insertIntoDB(XmlToDBSchema.java:37)
at testDB.XmlToDBSchema.createDBSchma(XmlToDBSchema.java:191)
at testXMLPar.testXML.main(testXML.java:16)
```

Comment: `VARCHAR2` can only be used if it is enabled (`varchar2_compat`)

Comment: And why do you have `PRIMARY KEY` in the middle of the statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error -204 refers to an undefined name which can have several reasons. [See here for an overview](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.messages.sql.doc/doc/msql00204n.html). In your case the statement has several issues:

- siteID does not have a type,
- primary key is in the middle of the statement, this should be moved to the end
- varchar2 can only be used if the database has been enabled for it, else you may get this error messages

To correct the errors you have to rewrite the statement, use data types where needed and to make sure that varchar2 support is enabled (check `get db cfg`).